# how to solve exception for the connection string(local database c#)

Tags: c#, mysql, database

ok so the first problem is the connection string itself it has this exception that i do not understand so i tried to put it in a try catch syntax but as i inserted it in the public partial class Form1 : Form the parenthesis are acting up so i inserted it in a function and now the fuction has this error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0161  'Form1.connection()': not all code paths return a value Restaurant Management System    C:\Users\admin\source\repos\Restaurant Management System\Restaurant Management System\Form1.cs  36  Active

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Restaurant_Management_System
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Black);
            label1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, Color.Beige);
            label2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Black);
            Password.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Black);

        }


        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;



        public SqlConnection connection()
        {
            try
            {
                 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= \"|Data Directory|\\Coffee(LoginEmployee).mdf\";Integrated Security=True;");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error message: COULD NOT CONNECT STRING: " + ex);
            }
        }


        private string getUsername()
        {
           SqlConnection con = connection();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT nalue FROM EmployeeLog where Property=Username", con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            return dr[0].ToString();
        }

        private string getPassword()
        {
            SqlConnection con = connection();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT nalue FROM EmployeeLog where Property=Password", con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            return dr[0].ToString();
        }
```

What do i need to replace? why does it not all return a value? if i use the void case it will also have this error that i cannot explicitly convert it to sqlconnection. this is made in the latest visual studio 2017

Comment: Can you see any line with a `return` inside your `connection()` function? I don't see any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you catch the exception, no SqlConnection will be returned. So you could return null after showing the message box.

Then of course, you will need to do a null check after calling connection() so you don't get a null reference exception trying to use it.

You also need to return the connection you are creating:

```
return new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|Data Directory|Coffee(LoginEmployee).mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
```

Note: I don't recommend hard-coding your connection string either! You would normally add the connection string to your app.config/web.config and read it using ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings... - this is because you might have different instance names on different machines, or you might want to point to a database on a server rather than local. You will not need to change the code and recompile just to make it work on more than one machine.

There is information on microsoft's class library site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) saying: `An error will be generated if a log file exists in the same directory as the data file and the 'database' keyword is used when attaching the primary data file. In this case, remove the log file. Once the database is attached, a new log file will be automatically generated based on the physical path.`

Comment: Even if he doesn't catch an exception. There's no `return` in his function

Comment: Haha. so there isn't

Comment: i would like to clarify why not hardcode the connection string? since i inserted the advised you told me now it raises the exception invalid value for attachDBfilename. can you recommend some format for the filename? i tried some formats from youtube but the thing is it does'nt work and raises the same exception it raises now. But the program now runs but when i enter the values the messagebox shows and the  new sql connection raises this exception

Comment: Answer updated. I have removed the \" and \\ from the connection string which might help. Ensure your data directory is correctly configured to where your mdf file is.

Comment: i just want to clarifyon how do i ensure that my mdf file is configured in the data directory. The database file and the forms are all in the same directory. And another clarification is how do i identify which of which file is a log file that i need to delete? Here are the names of the files in the same directory as my database files:                                          Folders: bin, obj, properties, Resources.                                                           Files: _Coffee_LoginEmployee_DataSet. Designer.cs, _Coffee_LoginEmployee_DataSet.xsc, _Coffee_LoginEmployee_DataSet.xsd

Comment: _Coffee_LoginEmployee_DataSet, App.config, Coffee(LoginEmployee).mdf, Coffee(LoginEmployee)_log

Comment: I think you should have an App_Data folder.

Comment: i updated my visual studio. Now i want to ask if the app_data shows after i create the project or after i make the table for connection? and also i want to know if this problem is caused by the update or something i forgot to install  cause when i started up the project the app data did not appear still even though i updated and included other extensions